# How to skip or ignore field in a Magento 2.3.4 import

Tags: magento2.3, import

I would like to update some products in Magento 2.3.4 admin>system>import. My import file doesn't have category info for items that are already in the database where they are assigned to a category.

I am concerned that if I leave the field blank it will clear the settings for the skus already in the data.

1-Can I remove the category column in the import file?

2-Is there something I can put in the field so it skips or ignores the column and does not update existing data for that field?

Answer (score 0):

To update products using import from csv
you can use the following

> Example CSV for updating price and qty

```
"sku","price","qty"
"test_sku1","100","10"
"test_sku2","123","12"
```

> Example CSV for importing new products

```
"sku","name","description","short_description","price","qty"
"test-sku1","Test product name1","Test product description1","Test product short description1","100","20"
"test-sku2","Test product name2","Test product description2","Test product short description2","10","30"
```

Just don't add attribute as column in csv which you don't want to update.

Comment: Thank you, for an import file that has some records with new data for that field and others that don't, is there a skip/ignore field word I can put into those fields like magmi's "__MAGMI_IGNORE__" ?

Comment: Are you using default magento import functionality to update products ?

Comment: Yes, Thank you, my files are mixed so I need an easy way to use those files without separating files

Comment: Great, Upvote and mark answer as right if it helped, eventually it will help magento community.